# Pagination of Elasticsearch results

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to extract data using `curl` commands vs. having to endlessly scroll through this page https://bubble.io/plugins

I believe the page sends requests and get results from Elasticsearch. Every request has a payload of {`x`: ***,`y`: ***, `z`: ***} which I believe keep track of the pagination.

Is there any way I can fabricate the pagination payload, so that I can simply extract all the data using a bash script that uses `curl`

This [attached](https://forum.bubble.io/uploads/default/original/3X/5/d/5da2dc0e3759d7e081ad238cfc22433b6faeda75.gif) gif explains the issue more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch has multiple ways to paginate results.

The easiest is using *from* and *size* tags in the query like a so

```
{
  "query": {
      ...
  },
  "size": 10,
  "from": 0
}
```

Even if is not the best performance way can be a life saver.

Another way to do it is use a scroller. That's fit really good with your needs and elastic community recommend it (check the link for more info https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#scroll-search-results)

You can check the other ways here https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/how-tos/elasticsearch-pagination-techniques/

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the inputs. I am actually looking for the exact way the site referenced in the question is requesting the data and handling the pagination. If you look at the attached `gif`, the site requests data using `mget` requests and handles the pagination with three coords `x`, `y` and `z`. I'm unable to figure out how to derive them without having to go through the browser.